# .replace does nothing when input is a variable

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace a variable globaly in a string, but so far this just returns the same string without modifying it, don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody point out what's happening?

```js
var line = "tooth";
var char = line.charAt(0);

line.replace(new RegExp(char,"g"), "");

console.log(line);
```

Comment: because `replace()` returns a new string, it doesn't change `line`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assign it again to the variable `line`

```
line = line.replace(new RegExp(char,"g"), "");
```